# Different view / method based on middleware using the same route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-fortify

I want to redirect logged in users to the `'/'` route (like `example.com`, without anything behind it)

This works:

`Route::get('/', Home::class)->name('home');`

```
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return view('dashboard');
        }
        else {
            return view('welcome');
        }
    }
}
```

But now I need to add middleware to this route / controller.

Documentation suggests adding `$this->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])` to the __constructor in my Home controller.

This doesn't work because it also affects the view for guests (`return view('welcome');`)

I also tried:

`Route::get('/', [Home::class, 'index'])->name('home');`

```
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->only('dashboard');
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $this->dashboard();
        }
        else {
            $this->welcome();
        }
    }
    
    public function welcome()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
    
    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: In order to use ``Auth``, you need middleware ``auth``.

Comment: why can't these be 2 different routes?

Comment: @lagbox when you go to `facebook.com`, you see a login / sign up form. After loggin in, you get redirected to the same url: `facebook.com`. I want the same thing in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when Googling for something similar, so I'm writing this for such people, sorry.

This looks like a very old version of Laravel that I'm not familiar with (and it's probably no longer supported), so I'll give my answer for Laravel 9.

To return different views, depending on whether they're logged in, use

```php
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/home', function() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('dashboard');
    } else {
        return view('welcome');
    }
});
```

If you have to use the result of some other policy and call controller methods, use

```php
// routes/web.php

use App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

Route::get('/settings', function () {
    if (Gate::allows('manageSystem')) {
        return (new Controllers\SettingsController)->index();
    } else {
        return (new Controllers\UserController)->settings();
    }
});
```

I haven't had a change to test this, but I hope this helps someone